# NSDate. Creating new date with same time

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have existing `NSDate` object what represents date and time of event. My task is to make copying function of existing event to other date with all attributes except day and month(but with saving of hours and minutes). I see `NSDate` documentation but here is no direct method for this. I can add few days with standard methods or `NSDateComponents` but  new date will be set with calendar, not with adding or substracting quantity days.

Is it a right way to extract "HH:mm" string from previous date, set it into formatted string and then convert it into new NSDate?

Comment: If you know the date you want to "target" then formatting/unformatting the date is not a terrible idea, but probably no better than using NSDateComponents.  (Hint, use NSDateComponents on old date to get hours/minutes/seconds, and then use NSDateComponents again on the new date, assign hours/minutes/seconds from old to new, and convert back to NSDate.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting to and from a string is probably not the best way. My suggestion would be to make an NSDateComponents from the date. Then you can set the month and day directly, and convert back to a date.

Answer (score 1):

You've already outlines all the bits you need:

1. Convert your NSDate to its components using NSDateComponents
2. Get the hours/minutes/seconds
3. Covert your new date to its components
4. Set tehe hours/minutes/seconds to the values you saved in step 2
5. Convert it back to a date again

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are already sufficient, but  here is my implementation using the other answers as a guide.

```
+ (NSDate*)useSameTimeAsDate:(NSDate*)priorDate butOnADifferentDate:(NSDate*)differentDate
{
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents  *priorComponents = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:priorDate];
    NSDateComponents *newComponents = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:differentDate];
    [newComponents setSecond:[priorComponents second]];
    [newComponents setMinute:[priorComponents minute]];
    [newComponents setHour:[priorComponents hour]];

    return [cal dateFromComponents:newComponents];
}
```